# Ubuntu is running in low-graphics mode

Tags: drivers, xorg, ubuntu-10.04, nvidia-graphics-card, linux-kernel

This error appears during Ubuntu 10.04 start up and I can run in low graphics mode. I tried to install the NVIDIA driver and then it works but when I reboot Ubuntu this error appears:

```
(EE) NVIDIA(0): Faild to initialize the NVIDIA kernel module. 
                please see the system's kernel log for additional error messages
                and consult the NVIDIA README for details.
(EE) NVIDIA(0): ***Aborting***
(EE) Screen(s) found, but none have a usable configuration.
```

I ran `nvidia-xconfig` and then restarted gdm but it's still broken.

Comment: not a programming question: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: I [Googled](http://www.google.com/search?q=nvidia+screens+found,+but+none+have+a+usable+configuration) the last error message - there are several results, most notably one from UbuntuForms and LinuxQuestions.

Answer (score 1):

I fought this problem for a long time with Ubuntu 10.04.2 and finally got the experimental Nvidia driver to load by installing Startup Manager, turning on Proposed updates, and using the Hardware Drivers menu option to install it.